# Nette Framework - Disable Latte macros

Tags: php, nette, latte

I'm using **Nette framework** which comes with Latte templates. My problem starts when I have **non-latte macros** inside my Latte template. Of course Latte throws an exception about invalid macros.

So how can I disable using Latte macros or just pass a blank HTML template instead of Latte into the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{syntax off}`

documentation https://latte.nette.org/en/macros#toc-syntax-switching